# NoPackagesFoundError: Package missing in current osx-64 channels python version

Tags: python, conda

I have  macosx 64 sierra

and I have run conda update conda

when I run `python -V`, I see
`Python 2.7.14`

when I run `python3 -V`, I see
`Python 3.7.5`

my env.yaml file is as such:

```
name: v-env
dependencies:
  - python=3.6.4
  - pip
  - pandas=0.19.2
  - geos
  - libxml2=2.9.4
```

when I run: `miniconda3/bin/conda env create --name v-env -f env.yml`, I get:

```
NoPackagesFoundError: Package missing in current osx-64 channels: 
  - python 3.6.4*
```

I'm using a 2017 version of Miniconda3 so not sure what version unfortunately but the file name is:
Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh since I'm trying to debug an old app that I didn't write.

when I run

`conda search main/osx-64::python=3.6.4`
I get

```
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
python                         3.6.4      hc167b69_0  main                
python                         3.6.4      hc167b69_1  main                
python                         3.6.4      hc167b69_3  main
```

and `conda info` returns

```
     active environment : None
       user config file : /Users/NAME/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.8.3
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.6.4.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=10.12.6
       base environment : //anaconda  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : //anaconda/pkgs
                          /Users/NAME/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : //anaconda/envs
                          /Users/NAME/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.3 requests/2.23.0 CPython/3.6.4 Darwin/16.7.0 OSX/10.12.6
                UID:GID : 2145864231:336272924
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Any advice on the python versions?

Comment: I can't replicate this, e.g., `conda search main/osx-64::python=3.6.4` turns up three builds, so if you have `defaults` in your channels, this should be working. Could you please edit the question to show the output of `conda info`?

Comment: @merv updated the question

Comment: Perhaps try explicitly adding a `channels:` section to the YAML, with ` - defaults` as the entry.

Comment: @merv that didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I just took out python=3.6.4 from my env.yaml file and that allowed me to get the virtual env created and source activate it. Then I ran python -V and I got
"Python 3.6.2 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc."
seems to be good enough for now